# How can I delete Chromium browser history at boot up on Raspberry Pi 4 B

Tags: linux

Playing the online game, *Forge of Empires*, I get the notice to clear cache.

This is run in Chromium Browser on my Raspberry Pi 4 B 4GB running Raspberry OS 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need a script to clear your history/cache. [This one](https://superuser.com/questions/509063/how-to-delete-chrome-temp-data-history-cookies-cache-using-command-line) is a good example, but it is written for Windows, so you will need to modify it to use bash and to use the paths for where Chromium is installed on your pi.

Next, you will need a way to run the script every time your pi starts. There are many ways to do this, one of which is crontab:

`sudo crontab -e`

`@reboot /bin/bash /home/pi/script.sh &`

Answer (score 0):

> Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) with desktop and recommended software. Image
> with desktop and recommended software based on Debian Buster.

Since it is Debian, you should look at /home/user/.cache directory.

I could find only two things connected to chromium on my debian based distributive:

```
/home/ubuntu/.config/chromium/
/home/ubuntu/.cache/chromium/
```

So, you might add such strings in your `/etc/rc.local` boot file. If there is no one, you should create it.

```
# echo """
/bin/rm -fr /home/ubuntu/.config/chromium/
/bin/rm -fr /home/ubuntu/.cache/chromium/""" >> /etc/rc.local
/bin/chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Replace `ubuntu` with you username. You can find it by `whoami`

```
# /bin/whoami
root
```

Now, `cache` and `config` will be deleted automatically each boot time.

Comment: Why do you talking about `Ubuntu`? The OP is using the Raspberry Pi OS. And please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: I'm using `ubuntu` - as a name of user, don't u see?  I know about `systemd`, and as you can read from the documentation, such basic principals of `initrc`, like boot scripts are supported. Not only 4 compatibility, but as author of systemd mentioned - it will be supported for-ever. So, you always can use /etc/rc.local - on any `systemd`-based distros, just to deploy something very fast. I've only tried to show topic-starter, how it is easy to erase all chromium's settings and cache by 2 lines only..

Comment: With using `/etc/rc.local` you are wrong. Please read the link I have provided carefully, in particular the last sentence: "*Note that there are some areas where systemd currently provides a certain amount of compatibility where we expect this compatibility to be removed eventually.*"